# Access a public non-static object from another separate class

Tags: java, swing, fonts, scope

I am trying to create my own `Font Chooser` class in another separate `class` from the file where I have my main class (a `JFrame` application), and I would like to access to the *textArea object* of the main `JFrame`, in order to modify its font properties, but I am not able to do it, because the textArea is a non-static object.

To solve this problem, I have thought to make the **separate class ("Font Chooser") an inner class**. In this the only solution?

**EDIT**

The `Font Chooser` object is instantiated **after the creation of the main Frame**, in fact the instantiation is done by the main JFrame class, and apparently I **cannot access to the main JFrame public members.**

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need a separate class. It doesn't make any sense to modify a non-static value from a static context. That's like wanting to paint your car red, so you try and change the color of the abstract concept of "car." You need to modify an instance of car, not the entire class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main recommendation: don't ignore OOP practices to solve your problem, such as by using public fields and such. Don't have another class directly manipulate the state of your JTextArea which should be private anyway. Instead, give the class that holds the JTextArea a public setFont method that other classes can call on valid instances of the containing class.

```
public class MyGui {
  private JTextArea textarea = .....;

  public void setTextAreaFont(Font font) {
     textarea.setFont(font);
  }
```

So for an object to call this method, all it needs is a **valid** reference to the MyGui class, with *valid* being the key term here. This may require that you pass the reference into the object that needs it by a setter method or a constructor parameter. There is no need to use an inner class here, none at all.

And of course, the JTextArea field should never be static as that would throw all OOP to the wind, making it very difficult maintaining, enhancing or testing your code.

---

**Edit**

You now state:

> The "Font Chooser" object is instantiated after the creation of the main Frame, in fact the instantiation is done by the main JFrame class, and apparently I cannot access to the main JFrame public members.

Then what is stopping you from passing the GUI class into your font chooser on its creation?

```
MyFontChooser myFontChooser = new MyFontChooser(this); // ???
```

Again, please tell the details of your problem.

```
class MyFontChooser {
  private MyGui myGui;

  public MyFontChooser(MyGui myGui) {
    this.myGui = myGui;
  }

  // some event caused method
  public void changeFont() {
    myGui.setTextAreaFont(someFont);
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but the "Font Chooser" class is created after the creation of the main JFrame and apparently I cannot access to its public members.

Comment: @bad_alloc: I don't understand your comment. Please elaborate since timing of class creation should have no bearing on this problem.

Comment: @bad_alloc The suggestion here is that you do not need a separate FontChooser class at all. Simply expose a method to allow the font of the internal text area to be changed.

Comment: I would like to create my own font Chooser class

Comment: @bad_alloc: and what does this class do? Show your code or describe it in detail. And if you create this class, what is preventing you from passing in a valid instance of the class that holds the JTextArea?

Comment: @bad_alloc: see edit to answer. Your edits to your question are just saying the same things you've said in your comments without giving us more detail. **Bolding** will not help. **Explanation** will!

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, today I am a bit tired

Comment: I needed a reference to the main class, otherwise I couldn't access its static public members, right dude

Comment: @bad_alloc: OK, we've shown you how to pass references. Problem solved, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually, it's better to pass to the FontChooser class a JTextArea object, which is what I really have to change the properties of. (Is this sentence correct? lol)

Comment: @bad_alloc: I disagree with that. I prefer that my classes strictly control what state changes happen to their fields, so that any changes go through the containing class. Else you risk having lots of side effects occurring that are difficult to keep track of.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But, in my case, I am passing a reference of the containing class (main) to an object of another class, which is instantiated inside my main class and which is not an inner class, but tries to emulate it. The only porpuse of the FontChooser class is to modify the textArea font of the main class, I don't want it to modify anything else, but maybe in the future??

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to have a reference to the JFrame you want to modify. I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    public MyFrame(){
        super();
        FontChooser fc = new FontChooser();
        fc.applyFont();
    }
}
class FontChooser{
    public void applyFont(){
        Font f;
        //code to set font values
        MyFrame.textArea.setFont(f);//Won't work, because textArea isn't static
    }
}
```

What you need is something like this

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    public MyFrame(){
        super();
        fc.applyFont(textArea)
    }
}
class FontChooser{
    public void applyFont(JTextArea textArea){//Notice the added parameter
        Font f;
        //code to set font values
        textArea.setFont(f);//Will work, because we have an instance of the object we want to modify.
    }
}
```

Obviously this needs to be modified for your code, but that's the idea. You need to pass a reference to the Object you want to modify.

Comment: The other dude has been faster but I have to thank also you!!

Comment: @bad_alloc ♥ glad you solved the problem

Comment: Today I am quite tired, so I am stupider than usual